# Get LinkButton Embedded Label value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Get LinkButton Embedded Label value?
Also issue with LinkButton on postback comes back empty. 
I basically need a clickable row to run a server side function is there a better way then a LinkButton?
I'm basically creating a search dropdown.

ASPX

```
   <asp:ListView ID="listView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <asp:Repeater ID="SearchResults" OnItemCommand="SetValues_ItemCommand" runat="server">

                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <div class="form-row">

                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="MemberInfo" runat="server" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start mb-2" OnClick="MemberInfo_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'>

                                                    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-2">
                                                        <h5 class="mb-1">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="PrimaryOrganization" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PrimaryOrganization") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </h5>
                                                    </div>

                                                </asp:LinkButton>

                                            </div>


                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:Repeater>
```

CS

```
             protected void MemberInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton MemberInfoBNT = (LinkButton)sender;
        bool bIsConverted = int.TryParse(MemberInfoBNT.CommandArgument.ToString(), out int index);
        if (bIsConverted)
        {

            Repeater SearchResultsObject = MemberInfoBNT.Parent.Parent as Repeater;
            ListViewDataItem listViewData = MemberInfoBNT.Parent.Parent.Parent as ListViewDataItem;
            int Listviewindex = listViewData.DataItemIndex;


            Label PrimaryOrganization = (Label)SearchResultsObject.Items[index].FindControl("PrimaryOrganization");

            TextBox registrantEmailValue = (TextBox)listView.Items[Listviewindex].FindControl("registrantEmail");
            registrantEmailValue.Text = PrimaryOrganization.Text;

        }

    }
```

[Image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPzfM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 provides you a customizable dropdownlist  with support for searching